# Can I use the Cache Manifest File with MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, offline

Is it feasible to write an ASP.NET MVC2 application that uses the Cache Manifest mechanism to support offline processing?  I know this might sound like a contradiction in terms, but I have an MVC2 web app and I'm looking at trying to make it resilient to unreliable network connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course that it is possible. The [HTML5 offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) storage is independent of the server side technology. Here's an [example with ASP.NET](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/26/creating-html5-offline-web-applications-with-asp-net.aspx). In this example the illustrated custom `IHttpHandler` could be easily replaced by a controller action in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: thanks.  However, what entries should go in the manifest file for URLs that do not have specific file references but are routed to controllers based upon the URL path?  Can you just add paths to the manifest file?  Thanks again.